# Folder & Subfolder Structure for Navigation with PHP

Tags: php, navigation, directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Help with PHP recursive navigation list menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909868/help-with-php-recursive-navigation-list-menu)

I am building a navigation system that is driven simply by the folder and subfolder directory structure on the server.

e.g.: gallery

- wedding
- nature

  - birds
  - cats
  - dogs
- aviation

  - fighter jets
  - commercial
  - wwii

Now I have this code worked out to this point but I am having trouble to make it format it into the necessary un-ordered list and list items for my navigation system.

```
<?php
function readDirs($path){
  $dirHandle = opendir($path);
  while($item = readdir($dirHandle)) {
    $newPath = $path."/".$item;

if(is_dir($newPath) && $item != '.' && $item != '..') {
    echo "<a href='$newPath'>$item</a>";
    readDirs($newPath);
  }
 }
}

$path =  "./galleries";
readDirs($path);

?>
```

Here is the html formatting that I require as output from the PHP:

```
    <ul>
        <li><a href="./galleries/wedding">wedding</a></li>
        <li><a href="./galleries/nature/">nature</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="./galleries/nature/birds/">birds</a></li>
                <li><a href="./galleries/nature/cats/">cats</a></li>
                <li><a href="./galleries/nature/dogs/">dogs</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="./galleries/aviation/">aviation</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="./galleries/aviation/fighter jets/">fighter jets</a></li>
                <li><a href="./galleries/aviation/commercial/">commercial</a></li>
                <li><a href="./galleries/aviation/wwii/">wwii</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Any help would be most appreciated in this matter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show what you you tried with regards to outputting your HTML source?

Comment: can you reword the question, I am not sure I understand what you are asking.

Comment: What you need is called recursion. http://devzone.zend.com/283/recursion-in-php-tapping-unharnessed-power/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909868/help-with-php-recursive-navigation-list-menu

Comment: @SamJ.Dennis So you have this function to get all your links figured out and right now it looks like it just echo's a links.  Have you tried to implement the cases where it outputs into ul/li structures?  If so, can you show that?

Comment: @Mike Brant: That is where I am at.  Working some new ideas via Flavius right now.  Will post results when I get them to work.

Comment: It might also interest you to check out the [Symfony Finder component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html) for whatever you might be trying to accomplish.

Comment: After beating my head against my computer all night, I have given up.  I really am no coder :( that being said this link below is exactly what I am looking for but it is done in C# rather than PHP.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504077/how-do-i-list-all-directories-and-subdirectories-in-an-unordered-list

If anybody knows how to translate this concept into PHP I would be more than grateful.  Cheers.

Comment: Too bad the reference to the "same question" is in relation to pulling the info from a DB rather than traversing a directory structure for the content for an UL.  I posted my working results over on the "other question".